# Eclipse maven Parent of resource marked as read only

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven, permissions

I get the following error when I try to add/refactor a class:

> Parent of resource:
>   /Users/Mike/git/switch-ingredients/maven/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/maven/Client.java
>   is marked as read only.

I have tried to give permissions to the files(**chmod 777**), I tried to restart eclipse and change the build path, but no success.

What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: take the ownership of file with chown

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked

Comment: I am glad it helped, I have added as answer you can mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can take the ownership of file with the [chown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) command